# Google maps inconsistent route rendering [Gmapsjs]

Tags: google-maps

I am using [Gmapsjs](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) to draw routes on map. Routes are rendered fully when I try to draw only one route but when adding a second route the route is not rendered fully. Please refer the picture below

http://s15.postimg.org/lc3wmd1bf/Capture.png

In the image you can see that route to a marker is missing but sometimes all the routes are properly set and sometime route is not set for all markers. Is this a problem with gmapsjs?

On each click I am assigning a new color to the markers and a route

```
var color = ['88511c','881c7d','1c8859','1c7788','1c3d88','c92a2a']; 
var colorname = ['brown','pink','green','teal','blue','red'];
var cl = 0;

$(document).on('click','.route',function(){
    initializeMap(routeArray);
});

function initializeMap(route){
if(route.length > 0){
  for(var i=0; i<route.length; i++){
    var next = i + 1;
    map.addMarker({
      lat: route[i].lat,
      lng: route[i].lon,
      infoWindow: {
        content: 'Name: '+route[i].name+' | Pincode: '+route[i].pincode
      },
      icon: 'maps/assets/icons/'+colorname[cl]+'.png'
    });
    if(next < route.length){
      map.drawRoute({
        origin: [route[i].lat, route[i].lon],
        destination: [route[next].lat, route[next].lon],
        travelMode: 'driving',
        strokeColor: '#'+color[cl],
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 3
      });
    }
  } // End for
  cl++;
}
map.fitZoom();
}
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of your `route` variable content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem fixed by doing nothing in the code. After clicking the first route I need to wait atleast for 3 seconds before clicking on the second route. It's all about the time interval between two routes rendering on a map.